# Webpack error when running cypress tests with cypress-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, cypress

I am writing cypress e2e tests for my nextjs web app, which uses firebase on the back end. I have followed the guide in the docs for setting it up using the cypress-firebase package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-firebase), but I am getting an error relating to webpack:

```
Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/cypress-firebase/lib-esm/plugin.js 18:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export default function pluginWithTasks(cypressOnFunc, cypressConfig, adminInstance, overrideConfig) {
|     // Only initialize admin instance if it hasn't already been initialized
>     if (adminInstance.apps?.length === 0) {
|         initializeFirebase(adminInstance, overrideConfig);
|     }
```

Here is the contents of my cypress/support/commands.js file (I am using firebase version 9.15.0, hence the imports from firebase/compat/*):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/database';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { attachCustomCommands } from 'cypress-firebase';


const fbConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);

attachCustomCommands({ Cypress, cy, firebase });
```

Here is the contents of my cypress.config.js file:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const cypressFirebasePlugin = require('cypress-firebase').plugin;
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return cypressFirebasePlugin(on, config, admin, { projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID });
    },
  },
});
```

I have a CYPRESS_TEST_UID in my .env file and have downloaded the serviceAccount.json file required by firebase-admin. I am not sure what is causing this error; any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using version 3.0.1 of the cypress-firebase plugin. Just upgraded myself and I get the exact same error.

Comment: Yea 3.0.1, did yours work on an earlier version?

Comment: Yes, did run 2.2.5 and it worked perfect so I downgraded back to that version.

Answer (score 0):

#### The error is coming from the `?` in the "Elvis" operator

```
     if (adminInstance.apps?.length === 0) {
^                          ^
#0                         #27
```

Counting from #0, character #27 is the `?`. This operator, `?.`, was added recently to Javascript, and is not expected by Webpack.

#### I am submitting a pull request to fix this

There are a few dozen other uses of `?.` in the package. We can work around this problem by rewriting them in the older format, e.g.

```
a ?. b
```

becomes

```
a && a.b
```

I have submitted a pull request

https://github.com/prescottprue/cypress-firebase/pull/900

Answer (score -1):

I also have the same problem just in 3.0.1; I am not sure if it is a plugin bug.

Comment: Have you had success with any other version of it?

Comment: Foe now Downgrade to version 2.2.5 and you should be good